# How to modify the the size of OBJECT TYPE TABLE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two different object types in my Oracle database.

One is :

```
create or replace TYPE "PERSONTYPE"  as object (   
EmployerName varchar2(30))
```

I can modify `EmployerName` varchar2 size as:

```
ALTER TYPE EMPLOYERTYPE
MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (EmployerName varchar2(40))
CASCADE;
```

This is working fine.

Another is:

```
create or replace TYPE "ITEMLIST"   as TABLE of varchar2(300);
```

I already have data on the table which is using `ITEMLIST`. Now, I want to change `varchar2(300)` to `varchar2(400)` without losing data. How to alter the size of `"ITEMLIST"` in this case?

Comment: What about `create or replace TYPE "ITEMLIST"   as TABLE of varchar2(400);`? You would replace the already existing type.

Comment: @KaushikNayak it will be a nested table column. You can't have a table of a collection type.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson : Oops, you're right, my bad.

Comment: It is a nested table for another table in my db. I wanted to make sure running that will not affect my existing data. There should be some cascading mechanism. But I am not aware of any.

Comment: `I already have data on the table which is using ITEMLIST`. I guess you cannot explicitly store data in nested table except using it in PLSQL block. What you mean when you say so? if you want to change then you must create and replace it like create or replace TYPE "ITEMLIST"   as TABLE of varchar2(400);`. No data is stored anywhere so nothing is lost.

Comment: @XING, what I am saying is, `ITEMLIST` is being used as a nested object to my another table. Will that table be affected ?

Answer (score 4):

> what I am saying is, `ITEMLIST` is being used as a nested object to my
>   another table. Will that table be affected ?

There is no obvious `ALTER` command to do so. Also, you won't be allowed to modify definition as you have an dependent object. But alternatively you can do work around. See below demo with inline explanation.

```
--Type of varchar(300)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ITEMLIST AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(300);
/
--Table Created 
CREATE  TABLE tt (col ITEMLIST) 
nested table
col
STORE AS
col1;
/
--Record Inserted
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(ITEMLIST(1));
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(ITEMLIST(3));
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(ITEMLIST(4));
/
--Record Selected
SELECT * FROM tt;         
/
--Created type of Varchar2(400) --New Size
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NEW_ITEMLIST AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(400);
/
--Alter table and added the new column with increased size
ALTER TABLE tt ADD (newcol NEW_ITEMLIST)  NESTED TABLE newcol STORE AS col2;
/
--Merged Records in Old column to new column.
MERGE INTO tt tb1
USING (SELECT * FROM tt) tb2
ON (tb1.col = tb2.col)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET tb1.newcol = CAST(tb2.col AS NEW_ITEMLIST) --You need to cast as the size differs even though the datatype remains same
WHERE tb1.col = tb2.col;    
/
COMMIT;
/
 --Drop old column of smaller size
ALTER TABLE tt DROP column COL;
/
--Again selected records to verify.
SELECT * FROM tt;
/
```